# Multiple Server to Single Server

Tags: java, tomcat, architecture, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I need to deploy my application in cloud.

In my present application architecture we use one server for every client. It will be costly when i moved the same thing to the cloud.

Can any one help me out to resolve it.

We use `Tomcat`, `SQL Server` and `Servlets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three Approaches to Managing Multi-Tenant Data

1. Uses a different database for each tenant.
2. Each tenant has its own separate set of tables in a common database.
3. All tenants share the same set of tables, and a Tenant ID associates each tenant with the rows that it owns.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) will give you more knowledge on it

Answer (score 2):

My experience is other way. Splitting large monolithic applications in to smaller application  is important especially when you move to cloud. It will make your application deployment and management much much easier. Applications will be more reliable too, When one goes down other one will still continue to work. Tomcat is really lightweight and it may not add too much cost when you compare other issues I pointed out here.

There are no straight forward answer if you really want to combine applications. You may need to manually figure out if all database can be combined to one instance, applications can be combined in to single one then test it to make sure everything works fine. I will discourage you from doing that based on my past experience.